# AND operator giving wrong output in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm firing this query

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders WHERE (CustomerID <> 51) AND (ShipperID <> 3);
```

and it is not showing **CUSTOMERS WITH 51** with different **shipperid**

**Why?**
is their any different view of AND in sql

so what if i want to exclude records with customerid with 51 and shipper id with 3 but show customerid with 51 and shipper excluding 3?

Comment: Your query selects all data that has **not** CustomerID 51 and **not** ShipperID 3. Please add example data and expected output

Comment: @juergend but it should show the records with customerID 51 and ShipperID 2

Comment: Then why do you tell sql server to select records `where customerID <> 51`?

Comment: `WHERE CustomerID = 51 AND ShipperID = 2`

Comment: @HoneyBadger doesbt AND operator returns true only if

Comment: (first condition = true) AND (second condition = true) = true   ???

Comment: Yes, and the first condition is `customerID <> 51` so records with `customerID = 51` are excluded.

Comment: @HoneyBadger but it should (true AND true) then only excluded what if i want to do that?

Comment: You are selecting records where BOTH conditions are true, Records where either condition is false are excluded. What exactly do you want if none of the answers suit your needs?

Comment: @HoneyBadger i want to exclude records only if it has CUSTOMER ID 51 AND SHIPPER ID AS 3

Comment: Thanks @HoneyBadger i got the answer but i dont understand how and works in sql now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated *it is not showing CUSTOMERS WITH 51 with different shipperid*
I think you rather mean to say

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = 51
```

> so what if i want to exclude records with customerid with 51 and
>   shipper id with 3 but show customerid with 51 and shipper excluding 3?

Then change your condition to be

```
SELECT * FROM Orders 
WHERE (CustomerID <> 51 AND ShipperID <> 3)
OR (CustomerID = 51 AND ShipperID <> 3);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul that does the work but i am bit confused about AND operator now

Comment: @omkomawar, you actually have two combination of condition and thus needs to separate them likewise I have shown.

Comment: Yeah thats why but i guess sql works with sets thats why it has this kind of weird behaviours

Comment: How can this be the correct solution if this WHERE-condition is exactly the same as `WHERE CustomerID IS NOT NULL AND ShipperID <> 3`?

Comment: @dnoeth, NO, it's not same as you mentioned. OP wants condition on specific customer ID and have two combination. See the EDIT in post properly.

Comment: It is. You compare `CustomerID <> 51` first and then `CustomerID = 51`. And then both add `AND ShipperID <> 3`. The 2nd condition is probably what the OP wanted based on his (a bit confusing) description.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `OR`:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM Orders o
WHERE (CustomerID <> 51) OR (ShipperID <> 3);
```

With `AND` it will return no rows with customer 51.  None, regardless of shipper.

Comment: but it should work if first condition and second condition must be true

Answer (score 1):

I might be misunderstanding you when you say "and it is not showing CUSTOMERS WITH 51", are you wanting to return customer id's of 51 that do not have shipperID of 3? If that's the case, you have your query to return customerid that does not equal 51 and shipper id that does not equal 3, so it won't return it. I'd do it like this

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE customerID = 51 AND shipperid <> 3;
```